# Listing all classes the java compiler needs during compilation

Tags: java, plugins, compilation, bytecode

**TL;DR**
I'm Looking for the `javac` plugin APIs which will allow me to log all classes needed by the Java compiler for a specific source file.

**More context:**
I'm writing a tool to migrate from `Maven` to `Bazel` and one of the challenges (and opportunities) there is that `Bazel` allows, and benefits from, a much finer grain granularity of "modules". Additionally dependencies aren't transitive with respect to compile classpath.

I'm trying to build a dependencies graph of the code and have used the bytecode plus heuristics on the source code (for constants, imports, etc.) but have stumbled on to an edge case which I fear, can only be solved by using a compiler plugin.

Given a method `Foo` in class `Concrete` which accepts an interface `SomeInterface` which extends `ParentInterface` then `javac` needs both `SomeInterface` and `ParentInterface` in the compile classpath although `ParentInterface` doesn't appear in the bytecode or in the source code.

This is solved in `Maven` because the dependencies **are** transitive with respect to compile classpath but I'd like to avoid that since this widens greatly the classpath (mainly interesting with respect to source dependnecies and build triggering).

I'm trying to see if I can use [compiler plugins](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/util/TaskEvent.html) to identify all classes the compiler needs for a given source file. This will help me since I can run my maven build once to collect the info and then generate the graph from this info. Problem is that I'm a bit lost with respect to the APIs.

Thanks!

Comment: You can examine SomeInterface to see it needs a ParentInterface. You can use either reflection or byte code analysis. If that sounds too hard I can assure you that trying to use the compiler to obtain this information is 10x harder.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks! Reflection probably won't help me since I'm interested in build time but byte code could work. Problem is that only in some of the cases I need the parent(s) and your approach mandates either learning all of these edge cases or expanding the scope to all auxiliary types and their ancestors (and this can of course be third party which complicates it further)...

Comment: yes. You will also need any classes obtained via reflection at runtime which could be harder to determine.

Comment: Consider posing the question on kythe discuss, they may be able to help with this. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kythe

Answer (score 0):

Well, the question which classes are needed for compilation IS transitive. So, no way to map this on a non-transitive dependency system, unless you pull all of them in the same module.

What you end up with is a graph, where nodes are class and an edge between A and B depicts that A is used in B. Now every class which is reachable from A needs to be in a dependency of A. You should be able to build modules as connected subgraphs.

So, for your example, after analyzing Concrete, you analyze SomeInterface, and then analyze ParentInterface. You build up the graph of direct dependencies as you go, and calculate transitive dependencies yourself.

As you resolve transitivity yourself, there is no need to do anything but byte code analysis (e.g. via ASM) to find the needed classes. The only dependency which will be lost in compilation is an unused import, which can be removed (and a lot of java style guides even say it has to be removed).

PS: Without knowing bazel, this sounds like you are making ways to small modules.

Comment: what you are describing is the full transitive closure which is not what I want. I want the smallest transitive closure I can live with and that can be achieved in one of two ways: 1. Compiler plugin to list all needed classes. 2. Understanding the dependency types where this is needed and prepare only for those. In Scala I'm using the former approach